Why does the actor_gradients calculate as [None, None, None, None]?
I'm trying to train a RL agent with DDPG policy to solve an Pendulum problem. An issue occurs when the policy attempts to train the parameter with the optimizers.Adam.apply_gradients. This is because the input actor gradient is being calculated as [None, None, None, None]. I find with weird when but the inputs of the actor gradient seem to have good values being input.
Here is the Code for clarification.
import gymnasium as gym
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


env = gym.make("Pendulum-v1") #render_mode="human" 

"""Get the state shape of the environment:"""

state_shape = env.observation_space.shape[0]

"""Get the action shape of the environment:"""

action_shape = env.action_space.shape[0]

"""Note that the pendulum is a continuous environment and thus our action space consists of
continuous values. So, we get the bound of our action space:
"""

action_bound = [env.action_space.low, env.action_space.high]


"""## Defining the variables

Now, let's define some of the important variables.

Define the discount factor, $\gamma$:
"""

gamma = 0.9

"""Define the value of $\tau$ which is used for soft replacement:"""

tau = 0.01

"""Define the size of our replay buffer:"""

replay_buffer = 5000

"""Define the batch size:"""

batch_size = 32

"""# Defining the DDPG class

Let's define the class called DDPG where we will implement the DDPG algorithm. For a clear understanding, you can also check the detailed explanation of code on the book.
"""

class DDPG(object):
    def __init__(self, state_shape, action_shape, high_action_value):
        self.replay_buffer = np.zeros((replay_buffer, state_shape * 2 + action_shape + 1), dtype=np.float32)
        self.num_transitions = 0
        
        self.noise = 3.0
        self.state_shape, self.action_shape, self.high_action_value = state_shape, action_shape, high_action_value
        
        # Actor and Critic Networks
        self.actor = self.build_actor_network(scope='Actor', trainable=True)
        self.target_actor = self.build_actor_network(scope='TargetActor', trainable=False)
        self.critic = self.build_critic_network(scope='Critic', trainable=True)
        self.target_critic = self.build_critic_network(scope='TargetCritic', trainable=False)
        
        # Optimizers
        self.actor_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
        self.critic_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
        
        # Soft update for target networks
        self.tau = 0.01
        self.soft_update_target_networks()
        
    def build_actor_network(self, scope, trainable):
        with tf.name_scope(scope):
            inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(self.state_shape,))
            layer_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation=tf.nn.tanh, name='layer_1', trainable=trainable)(inputs)
            actor = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.action_shape, activation=tf.nn.tanh, name='actor', trainable=trainable)(layer_1)
            scaled_actor = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x * self.high_action_value, name="scaled_a")(actor)
            return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=scaled_actor)
    
    def build_critic_network(self, scope, trainable):
        with tf.name_scope(scope):
            state_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(self.state_shape,))
            action_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(self.action_shape,))
        
            # Define first layer weights and biases
            w1_s = tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, trainable=trainable)(state_input)
            w1_a = tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, trainable=trainable)(action_input)
        
            # Combine state and action pathways
            net = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([w1_s, w1_a])
            net = tf.keras.layers.Activation('tanh')(net)
        
            # Final critic output
            critic = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, trainable=trainable)(net)
            
            return tf.keras.Model(inputs=[state_input, action_input], outputs=critic)
    
    def soft_update_target_networks(self):
        for target_param, param in zip(self.target_actor.trainable_variables, self.actor.trainable_variables):
            target_param.assign(self.tau * param + (1 - self.tau) * target_param)
        
        for target_param, param in zip(self.target_critic.trainable_variables, self.critic.trainable_variables):
            target_param.assign(self.tau * param + (1 - self.tau) * target_param)
    
    def select_action(self, state):
        action = self.actor(state[np.newaxis, :])
        action = np.random.normal(action, self.noise)
        action = np.clip(action, action_bound[0], action_bound[1])
        return action
    
    def train(self, batch_size=32):
        self.soft_update_target_networks()
        
        indices = np.random.choice(replay_buffer, size=batch_size)
        batch_transition = self.replay_buffer[indices, :]
        
        batch_states = batch_transition[:, :self.state_shape]
        batch_actions = batch_transition[:, self.state_shape: self.state_shape + self.action_shape]
        batch_rewards = batch_transition[:, -self.state_shape - 1: -self.state_shape]
        batch_next_state = batch_transition[:, -self.state_shape:]
        
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            critic_values = self.critic([batch_states, batch_actions])
            target_action = self.target_actor(batch_next_state)
            target_critic_values = self.target_critic([batch_next_state, target_action.numpy()])
            y = batch_rewards + gamma * target_critic_values
            critic_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - critic_values))
                 
        critic_gradients = tape.gradient(critic_loss, self.critic.trainable_variables)
        print(critic_gradients)
        self.critic_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(critic_gradients, self.critic.trainable_variables))
        
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            target_action2 = self.actor(batch_states)
            actor_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(self.critic([batch_states, target_action2.numpy()]))
        
               
        actor_gradients = tape.gradient(actor_loss, self.actor.trainable_variables)
        print(actor_gradients)
        self.actor_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(actor_gradients, self.actor.trainable_variables))
    
    def store_transition(self, state, action, reward, next_state):
        trans = np.concatenate((state, action, [reward], next_state), axis=None)
        index = self.num_transitions % replay_buffer
        self.replay_buffer[index, :] = trans
        self.num_transitions += 1
        if self.num_transitions > replay_buffer:
            self.noise *= 0.99995
            self.train()

"""## Training the network

Now, let's start training the network. First, let's create an object to our DDPG class:
"""

ddpg = DDPG(state_shape, action_shape, action_bound[1])

"""Define the number of episodes:"""

num_episodes = 5000

"""Define the number of time steps in each episode:"""

num_timesteps = 50

#for each episode
for i in range(num_episodes):

    #initialize the state by resetting the environment
    state, info = env.reset()

    #initialize the return
    Return = 0

    #for every step
    for j in range(num_timesteps):

        #render the environment
        env.render()

        #select the action
        action = ddpg.select_action(state)
        
        
        #print(action)
        #print(action[0])
        

        #perform the selected action
        next_state, reward, done, truncated, info = env.step(action[0])  # Corrected

        #store the transition in the replay buffer
        ddpg.store_transition(state, action, reward, next_state)

        #update the return
        Return += reward

        #if the state is the terminal state then break
        if done:
            break

        #update the state to the next state
        state = next_state

    #print the return for every 10 episodes
    if i %10 ==0:
         print("Episode:{}, Return: {}".format(i,Return))

"""Now that we learned how DDPG works and how to implement DDPG, in the next section,
we will learn another interesting algorithm called twin delayed DDPG.
"""

I checked first to see if the actors outputs were to complicated for the gradient, because I have a scaling layer I thought this might be the case, but without that scaling layer the issue still occurred.
